# Measure population on several dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, count, distinct

I want to measure the population of our manucipality (which contains out of several places). I've got two tables in: my first dataset is a calender table with a row for each first day of every month.
My second table contains alle the people that live and have lived in the manucipality.
What I want is the population of each place on every first day of the month from my calender table. I've put some raw data below (just a few records of the persons table because it contains 100.000 records)

Calender table:

```
+----------+
|   Date   |
+----------+
| 1-1-2018 | 
+----------+
| 1-2-2018 | 
+----------+
| 1-3-2018 | 
+----------+
| 1-4-2018 | 
+----------+
```

Persons table

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| BSN | Startdate |  Enddate  | Date of death | Place |
+-----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
|  1  | 12-1-2000 |   null    |    null       |   A   |
+-----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
|  2  | 10-5-2011 |   null    |    22-1-2018  |   B   |
+-----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
|  3  | 16-12-2011| 10-2-2018 |    null       |   B   |
+-----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
|  4  | 9-11-2012 |   null    |    null       |   B   |
+-----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
|  5  | 8-9-2013  |   null    |    27-3-2018  |   A   |
+-----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
|  6  | 7-10-2017 | 28-3-2018 |    null       |   B   |
+-----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
```

My expected result:

```
+----------+-------+------------+
|   Date   | Place | Population |
+----------+-------+------------+
| 1-1-2018 |   A   |     2      |
+----------+-------+------------+
| 1-1-2018 |   B   |     4      |
+----------+-------+------------+
| 1-2-2018 |   A   |     2      |
+----------+-------+------------+
| 1-2-2018 |   B   |     3      |
+----------+-------+------------+
| 1-3-2018 |   A   |     2      |
+----------+-------+------------+
| 1-3-2018 |   B   |     2      |
+----------+-------+------------+
| 1-4-2018 |   A   |     1      |
+----------+-------+------------+
| 1-4-2018 |   B   |     1      |
+----------+-------+------------+
```

What I've done so far but doesnt seems to work:

```
SELECT a.Place
,c.Date
,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(b.BSN))
FROM Person as b
WHERE b.Startdate < c.Date
AND (b.Enddate > c.Date OR b.Enddate is null)
AND (b.Date of death > c.Date OR b.Date of death is null)
AND a.Place = b.Place) as Population
FROM Person as a
JOIN Calender as c
ON a.Startdate <= c.Date
AND a.Enddate >= c.Date
GROUP BY Place, Date
```

I hope someone can help finding out the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like a _conditional aggregation_ problem: `sum( case ... end )` where the `case` expression evaluates to `1` or `-1` depending on the various comings and goings.

Answer (score 0):

First cross join `Calender` and the places to get the date/place pairs. Then left join the persons on the place and the date. Finally group by date and place to get the count of people for that day and place.

```
SELECT [ca].[Date],
       [pl].[Place],
       count([pe].[Place]) [Population]
       FROM [Calender] [ca]
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                               [pe].[Place]
                               FROM [Persons] [pe]) [pl]
            LEFT JOIN [Persons] [pe]
                      ON [pe].[Place] = [pl].[Place]
                         AND [pe].[Startdate] <= [ca].[Date]
                         AND (colaesce([pe].[Enddate],
                                       [pe].[Date of death]) IS NULL
                               OR coalesce([pe].[Enddate],
                                           [pe].[Date of death]) > [ca].[Date])
       GROUP BY [ca].[Date],
                [pl].[Place]
       ORDER BY [ca].[Date],
                [pl].[Place];
```

Some notes and assumptions:

- If you have a table listing the places use that instead of the subquery aliases `[pl]`. I just had no other option with the given tables.
- I believe the `Date of death` also implies an `Enddate` for the same day. You might want to consider a trigger, that sets the `Enddate` automatically to the `Date of death` if it isn't null. That would make things easier and probably more consistent.